# How to select all the elements in the pandas series except specific element

Tags: pandas, series

I have a pandas series like following.

```
cluster_quantity
Out[199]: 
Clusters
Cluster 1     5
Cluster 2     4
Cluster 3     3
Cluster 4    16
Cluster 5     1
Cluster 6     4
```

Then I have constraint like following

```
## Identifying clusters more than 6 order quantity
cluster_grtr_6 = np.where(cluster_quantity > 6)

cluster_grtr_6
Out[201]: (array([3], dtype=int64),)
```

Now I have to extract all the elements of the series except cluster_grtr_6 value
How to drop the 3rd location i.e. `Cluster 4    16`  from series

What I am doing is

`cluster_quantity.loc[~cluster_grtr_6 ]`

But, it doesn't work. Please help

Answer (score 0):

What I did is

```
cluster_quantity.drop(cluster_name.index)

Clusters
Cluster 1    5
Cluster 2    4
Cluster 3    3
Cluster 5    1
Cluster 6    4
```

Comment: presumably this would work `cluster_quantity[cluster_quantity <= 6]`